# "A word that means wicked and also the highest degree or most extreme form of something"

Tags: single-word-requests

Petty treason is betraying your master, and high treason is betraying your country; I want a word for the third and highest kind of treason.

Example:

> He betrayed the human race to join the aliens and thus he was guilty of _____ treason.

Comment: *Sedition* is a type of treason, but it's not an adjective that means *utmost*.

Comment: Your question and comment pre-supposed there's is some kind of well-established or at least broadly recognized "third kind" of treason. There isn't. You're going to have to employ a standard adjective, such as Fergus' "ultimate".

Comment: Then wouldn't there also be a fourth kind of treason for betraying Star Fleet or the Empire, or whatever coalition of races exists in your world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you will find an official term; as you noted, *petty treason* and *high treason* are degrees based on the entity that was betrayed. It is unlikely that the English language will have settled on a single term for treason that is greater than *high treason* (treason against a sovereign), because such a term would not historically have been necessary.

With that said, for your science fiction example, you should feel free to use creative license in developing a term. I would suggest using a synonym of *utmost*, such as:

- extreme treason
- highest treason
- peak treason
- ultimate treason
- utmost/uttermost treason
- zenithal treason

...and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

[***supreme treason***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=supreme+treason%2Csupreme+treachery&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csupreme%20treason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csupreme%20treachery%3B%2Cc0).

> supreme
>
> : highest in degree or quality : greatest or highest possible [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supreme)

***the most ignominious treason***

> ignominious
>
> 1 :  marked with or characterized by disgrace or shame :  dishonorable
>
> 2 :  deserving of shame or infamy :  despicable [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignominious)

***the most [infamous treason](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=infamous+treason%2Cignominious+treason%2Cinfamous+treachery%2Cignominious+treachery&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinfamous%20treason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cignominious%20treason%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinfamous%20treachery%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cignominious%20treachery%3B%2Cc0)***

> infamous
>
> 1 :  having a reputation of the worst kind :  notoriously evil
>
> 2 : causing or bringing infamy :  disgraceful
>
> 3 : convicted of an offense bringing infamy [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infamous)
>
> *People, a horrible treason, an infamous treason threatens our independence, our adored independence, for which our fathers gave their lives!* [Eagles and Empire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lJasmxZqUBYC&pg=PA93&dq=%22infamous+treason%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBzgKahUKEwjTtpX7uJXJAhUBqxoKHTAeCWo#v=onepage&q=%22infamous%20treason%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

'Superlative treason' could be one construction? 'Ultimate' or 'total' could be others.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer looks more like a comment than an answer. Please visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/answering) to see how it works here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "the highest treason" may be the most appropriate phrase here. It is also the title of a short story by science fiction writer Randall Garrett, which describes a betrayal not entirely unlike your example.